# Call ApplicationStart Method in Global.asax Without a Request

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-8

I'm publishing my asp.net site with iis( my local machine has iis v8, server's iis v7 ). 
But I want to start a function in Global.asax.cs immediately without calling a page.

*When I call a page, global.asax.cs Application_Start method launches. I want to launch it without a page call request.*

```
namespace ProductService.XmlFeed
{
    public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FtpUploaderMain.RegisterCacheEntry(); //this method I want to start without page call
        }

        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SimpleLogger.WriteLog("Application Started without a page call","D:\\log.txt");

            RegisterRoutes();

            //FtpUploaderMain.RegisterCacheEntry();
        }

        private void RegisterRoutes()
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Products", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(ProductXmlFeedService)));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PreLoad enabled feature of IIS8 -
For IIS 7.5 use application- initialization -

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization